# 403 forbidden from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have completed the Notes App tutorial on https://serverless-stack.com (the only change being that I am connecting to a MongoDB).
The Notes App was created by using the infrastructure ymls in 'Resources'.
Everything is working.

I then decided to alter the serverless.yml and add back in the supplied ‘hello’ api (including adding the handler.js to the project).
This API simply returns a message.
With that done I then executed `$serverless deploy —stage dev`
The Notes app continues to work.

Executing the ‘hello’ API in the Amazon API Gateway gives 200, ok.
When I run an `npx aws-api-gateway-cli-test` with the `—path-template=‘/hello’` it gives me a ’403 forbidden’.
When I run  `npx aws-api-gateway-cli-test` with the `--path-template=‘/notes’` it gives me 200, ok.

I don’t understand why the call to ‘hello’ is 403 forbidden?

**Aside**: the reason I added the supplied ‘hello’ API back in is because I have also set up a new project (in the same way as the Notes app) that is having the same issue - I can’t call any of this new projects APIs (which I have written) as they all give ’403 forbidden’.

Here is the ‘hello’ API as defined in the serverless.yml:

```
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

I have verified that:

`npx aws-api-gateway-cli-test` is being called with `--path-template=’/hello’`.

`npx aws-api-gateway-cli-test` defaults to GET.

The `--invoke-url=‘https://“ID”.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev’` looks ok too.

The path is defined in serverless.yml as ‘hello’ with a method of GET.

The handler is called `handler.js` and contains a function called `hello` (as supplied by the tutorial).

Checking in `API Gateway > Stages > dev` the Invoke URL is given as `https://“ID”.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/hello`.
(In both cases “ID” is replaced with the correct matching ID without quotes)

The only other difference from the tutorial is, as I am not connecting to Dynamo, I don’t have any iamRoleStatements defined in the serverless.yml.

Any help greatly appreciated as I completely new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You basically answered your question

> I don’t have any iamRoleStatements

You need to ensure proper IAM roles are supplied for lambda service and API gateway. They do not come preconfigured.

Comment: Possibly, but why do all the other APIs (create, delete, get) in the Notes app work just fine? (The Notes App is working, I can create notes, store notes to MongoDB etc.)  I haven't defined any iamRolesStatements for them either? Why is it just the 'hello' API that is giving 403 when all the others give 200?